# difference between using arr[i] and arr.length in the for loop definition in javascript

Tags: javascript

I came across something I've never seen before and I like it. check examples below:

```
var arr = ['un', 'deux', 'trois', 'quatre', 'cinq', 'six', 'sept'];

for(var i = 0; arr[i]; i++){
  console.log( arr[i] );
}
```

instead of:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  console.log( arr[i] );
}
```

But they both achieve the same result, which is to output a list of array.

My question is, what's the difference (or similarity) between using 'arr[i]' and 'arr.length' in the ***for loop*** declaration?

Many thanks

Comment: You need to be careful with `for(var i = 0; arr[i]; i++){` in case there is a null value inside the array.

Comment: In terms of performance there is no (big) difference. In both cases you are accessing a property of `arr`.

Comment: You will also most often want to cache array’s length in a variable, like `for ( var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i += 1 ) { //... }` in order to not “calculate” the length,  and also because depending on the nature of what you are doing arr.length can actually change while running the loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var arr = ['un', 'deux', 'trois', null, 'cinq', 'six', 'sept'];
```

How about now?

```
delete arr[2];
```

How about now?

The difference shows up as soon as you have falsy values in the array, or discontinuities in keys (such as those created by using the `delete` operator). The `length` loop will yield the falsy value and continue, the other one will stop.

Answer (score 2):

```
i < arr.length
```

this statement checks in every loop if `i` is smaller then the **length** of `arr`

```
arr[i]
```

here, every loop cycle checks if `arr` at **position** `i` is truthy.

Comment: "set" is misleading. "`arr` is a truthy value at **position** i"

Comment: To be pedantic: `arr[i]` checks if the value is truthy and not if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Let's ask [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/arr-i-vs-arrlength/2) for this.

Comment: You need to reset the `len` variable for the `while(len--)` test. I'm pretty sure jsPerf doesn't reset each time the test runs.

Comment: I added two test cases from the comments in http://jsperf.com/arr-i-vs-arrlength/2. Also, @patrick is right.

Comment: Yup you guys are both correct, I 'm editing  my post to point to Kay's revision. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `arr[i]` as the continue condition checks the *truthiness* of the element at that position in the array. This is a cute trick, but won't work if you want to iterate over arrays containing falsy values, like

```
[1, 4, 6, 0, 3, 9]
// or
[true, 'seven', false, -1, {foo: 'bar'}]
```

Using `i < arr.length` checks that the current index is less than the total length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop iterates as long as the condition part of it is true. First time the condition is false the loop stops.

`arr[i]` is true as long as the value is **not** one of the following: false, 0, empty string, null, undefined, NaN

`i < arr.length` checks that `i` is less than the size of the array, which is what you should do.

Comment: or `NaN`, `false`, `undefined`.

Comment: @Felix, thanks for pointing that out. I was thinking a bit too perlish. ;)